# Monitor Git remote load

Tags: git, ssh

I have a server that works as remote for small project that is extremely often read. (by "having" I mean I have full root access to both repo and host Centos 7).

Clients use ssh for fetching / cloning my repo, but I would like to monitor: how often why actions are being performed on my Git repo? I know how to monitor pushes to it - by hooks, but how to monitor fetches and clones?

I am interested:

- what ref is being "asked" for?
- how much data is transferred with given request
- count "git archive" command requested remotely.

Any ideas?